# I have a problem in my code concerning Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have this problem about Unhandled promise rejection , in this code above , i want to save a document which is stage in a mongodb document but it appear this code . How would i fix it ?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this important document: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: then, change `const stage =` to `let stage =`

Comment: Hi , i change it but it doesn't work !

Comment: i integrate the try/catch block , it appear a message : stage is not defined

Comment: Please never post screenshots of code but post the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Node.js global `process` to catch the error and log the stack trace.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
  console.log('unhandledRejection', error.stack);
});
```